# How to improve Guice performance at startup

Tags: java, performance, guice

Ok, I know my computations are not objective and so on, but anyway, I hate to wait so much time when performing my unit-tests:

My guice swing application takes about 7 seconds to initialize. It's a simple IRC client. At that moment, no connection are open, I even haven't called any java.io or java.net classes yet. I've tried to narrow down what exactly is wrong and I get that 5.8 seconds (average) are used by Guice in order to create the injector with the 2 modules I'm using (one normal module and one built with `FactoryModuleBuilder`, installed within the original module).

When I remove all modules (so basically calling only and exactly `Guice.createInjector()`), it still takes 3.5 seconds.

The version of Guice I use is the 3.0 rc2. My computer is certainly not the latest, but it is still not older than 3 years.

So how can I improve Guice's performance, if possible?

---

For reference, here's the main method I'm using, causing the 3.5 seconds. Subsequent calls take 0.01 second

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector();
    long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(((t1 - t)) / 1000.0);
}
```

And the result

```
3.578
```

Comment: There must be something wrong either with your computer or with the RC. Mine is 2 years old, I'm using Guice 2, and empty `Guice.createInjector()` takes 0.140 s on the first invocation. Guice is quite fast, but in unit tests it's recommended not to use DI, since you can wire it up manually most of the time.

Comment: For the record, you should use `System.nanoTime()` rather than `System.currentTimeMillis()` for timing things. `System.currentTimeMillis()` is "wall clock time"... the Javadoc for those methods explains a bit more. That certainly wouldn't affect the timing here significantly though.

Comment: Well, at first my tests were with nanoTime(). But when I saw the long loading time, I thought that it might somehow be linked to that method so I came back to the (good old) currentTimeMillis(). Since the results are the same with both methods, I didn't care about changing it back to nanoTime().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You shouldn't need to use Guice in unit tests. If you do need to use it, they probably aren't really unit tests (which test things in *isolation*) or you aren't using Guice correctly or both.
- Guice definitely shouldn't be taking any number of seconds to start up unless there's something in your code causing something weird. On my machine (with 3.0 rc2) it takes a little over 100ms to create an `Injector` with `Guice.createInjector()` and no modules.

Comment: Ok, not wanting to falmebait, but does that mean that Guiceberry is a unuseful framework? Regarding the second point: I'll try on my home computer as soon as I come back home, but right now, it's really annoying.

Comment: Anyway, the reason why I test with Guice is that I need to test my module. That's in fact why I'm using Guice inside unit-tests.

Comment: @Frór: Personally, I don't use Guice in unit tests... tests of groups of classes together (i.e. integration tests, end-to-end tests) do make sense for using Guice. I haven't used Guiceberry so I can't really speak to that. Anyway, there are legitimate uses for Guice in tests so I'm not going to argue that point more.

Comment: With my home computer, it's indeed much quicker... 0.25 seconds for the empty injector. I don't know what's going on on my work computer. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @ColinD You do need to use Guice in unit tests if you are testing `Activity` and `Fragment` classes in Android. In Roboguice there's an explicit call for injection at a certain point in the lifecycle of these objects that allows for injection, because the system creates Activities and requires a default constructor for both the Activity and Fragment classes. All the rest of the code however is game for dependency injection (constructor) which of course does not require the use of Guice (or any other DI container)