# General Guice performance guidelines

Tags: java, performance, guice

I currently have a command-line tool that uses Guice and its extensions fairly heavily.

After completing the functionality of the tool, I've determined that the performance is sub-standard, and started profiling using simple hprof.

This has pointed out that just creating the Injector is a significant performance problem.  I generally avoid doing any real work in Modules, and reserve compute intensive work for Providers...

With that given, what are some general performance guidelines for Guice?  Should I avoid using @AssistedInject and FactoryModuleBuilders?  Avoid @Singletons if possible?  Ensure that all bindings are explicit and avoid JIT bindings?

I've searched all over, but can't really find much addressing basic Guice performance other than people saying it's really fast.

Comment: Well, modules are evaluated only once, but providers many times. Hence I would do it exactly the other way if there is _any_ way to get the desired effect. Also Singletons: Why avoid them? Embrace them. Work done once cannot be slower than work done twice.

Comment: This doesn't necessarily answer the question...from profiling I observe that just the createInjector call is half of my processing time.

Comment: Did your profiling include or exclude the times for classloading, GC and JIT? Also: Did you check the question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748405/how-to-improve-guice-performance-at-startup] ?

Comment: Do you really have a performance problem (like an unresponsive application), or are you trying to improve the performance just for the sake of it? Maybe the injector takes half the time because the rest of the application code doesn't have much to do. Dependencies are typically injected at startup, and then the app runs without Guice being involved. What does your app do?

Comment: It depends on the particular command issued.  Some commands take neglible time, other commands spend quite a bit of time...  At least for now, I've switched over to Dagger.  In terms of runtime, it cuts off a decent amount.

Answer (score 6):

First off, your question leaves a lot to be desired. What is "sub-standard" performance and how did you decide what that means? It is arbitrary? Do you have a user who thinks it's too slow? Does it take to long to start or too long to produce results from user interaction?

Without actual code to evaluate, it's hard to debug performance issues. Here are some tips from my experience:

1. Only create the injector once. I saw a project where they were creating an injector for every REST request and it had horrible performance. When they stopped doing that, their API got 15x faster. If you NEED to create   multiple injectors through your code, I would strongly suggest refactoring so you don't need to.
2. Singletons can be great for performance, just don't misuse it. They are only created once, which  can happen as soon as you create your injector (eager singletons) or when they are first requested by something else in the object graph.
3. Understand that Guice is a reflection based library and reflection is ALWAYS slow. Guice does an excellent job of being very fast at runtime, at the expense of a lot of reflection when you create an injector (see item 1). If you are seeing noticeable lag in your application, it probably means you are doing something wrong.

Lastly, if you decide that you just can't handle Guice's performance "issues", you could try out an alternative like Dagger from [Square](http://square.github.io/dagger/) (version 1) and [Google](http://google.github.io/dagger/) (version 2). It uses code generation instead of reflection so you don't have the reflection cost, but it's not as full featured and doesn't have the extensions.

Comment: ...great summary. just thought i'd clarify one small point - Dagger 1 does indeed use reflection, whereas Dagger 2 does not.